# How to start a web server with Suave using HTTPS protocol?

Tags: f#, suave

I have read the [Suave document](https://suave.io/Suave.html) but still cannot start a Suave web server using HTTPS protocol.

Can someone help me on this? It would be great if sample code is provided.

Comment: What do you mean by "cannot start using https protocol"? How are you hosting your server and what unexpected behaviour are you seeing?

Comment: I just want clients (web browsers) can access my website using https. I just compile my app to exe file and execute it. For http it works fine.

Comment: @NghiaBui - In https://suave.io/binding.html, it says "the current recommendation for deploying HTTPS is by letting a reverse proxy manage the HTTPS termination." The simplest reverse proxy to set up is [Nginx](https://www.nginx.com/); see ["What is a Reverse Proxy Server?"](https://www.nginx.com/resources/glossary/reverse-proxy-server/) and the [Nginx docs](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/) for more details. If you still need help, ask a new question about nginx.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an HTTPS binding like this:

```
let cert = new X509Certificate2("certificate.p12","easy")
let ssl =  HttpBinding.createSimple (HTTPS cert) "127.0.0.1" 8443
```

The certificate needs to be in PKCS format.